# Getting Data Back from Async Future function in Flutter

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart, async-await

I'm new a newbie in Flutter and kinda struggling a bit while handling the asynchronous and (Future methods). So, after getting data correctly from the database and populating it in the Users object want it to use in widgets. However, I'm not sure about how to get data back from **_query** method.

I believe there is a correct way to do it. Below is what I'm trying to do.  Moreover, Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
class _OutPutDBState extends State<OutPutDB> 
    {
      List<User> users = List<User>.empty(growable: true);
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
        return Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: Container(
                child: Card(
                  child:Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                        ElevatedButton(onPressed: _query, child: Text('Get User Name')),
    
                        **Text(users[1].name), // Getting Issue Here . Want to get data populated in  Widgets. Error : RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 1**   
                    ],
                  )
                ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
```

---

```
Future<List<User>> _query() async
  {
    final dbHelper = DatabaseHelper.instance;
    final allRows = await dbHelper.queryAllRows();
    print(allRows.length);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < allRows.length; i++) {
      users.add(User.fromMap(allRows[i])); //Working Fine .. Getting Data from 
       //users[i].toMap();
    }
    
    print(users[1].name); // Work Fine
    return users;
  }
```

Comment: im not sure what you mean, it prints users[1].name but does not returns the complete list?

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60061606/how-do-i-get-data-from-an-sqflite-table-and-display-it-as-a-inside-text-widget/60062895#60062895) answers your question

Comment: It's difficult to understand what is your problem !!!

Comment: @JaimeOrtiz users[1].name doesn't print the name. it throws the error which I mentioned. this is just an example. I actually want to Return the Users list from Data and populate it in widgets.

Comment: Yeah, Future Builder method seems like the last resort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting that error because your list still empty, you have to update the state when you know you have received data.

In this code block you're calling that Future mehotd which returns a list, but you are not catching that list.

```
ElevatedButton(onPressed: _query, child: Text('Get User Name')),

Text(users[1].name), // Error
```

Taking your code as example it can be like this way:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FutureExampleScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const FutureExampleScreen({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FutureExampleScreenState createState() => _FutureExampleScreenState();
}

class _FutureExampleScreenState extends State<FutureExampleScreen> {

  List<User> users = List<User>.empty(growable: true);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: Card(
            child:Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: Text('Get User Name'),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    final data = await _query();
                    setState(() => users = data);
                  }, 
                ),
                if ( users.isNotEmpty ) Text(users[1].name!),
              ],
            )
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

User class and _query method.

```
class User {
  final String? name;
  final int? age;
  User({this.name, this.age});
}

Future<List<User>> _query() async {

  final user1 = User( name: 'Dart', age: 21 );
  final user2 = User( name: 'Flutter', age: 20 );

  final list = [user1, user2];

  await Future.delayed( const Duration( milliseconds: 300 ) );

  return list;
}
```

I have created User class and _query function just to complement the example.

Comment: Future Builder is Cool also. Better data handling in widgets either getting data in from an API or a Local Database

Comment: Yes, FutureBuilder is commonly used when you want to load data and handle the UI knowing when it is already loaded or not, there is a lot of ways to implement our ideas, ones betters than others.

Answer (score 0):

You are indeed calling your Future but you are not retrieving the return value from it.
Try to expand the onPressed function in order to save the data:

```
onPressed: () async { 
    setState(() {
       users = await _query(); 
    });
}
```

You should also look into FutureBuilder.
Since your data is coming from a Future, you should not print it directly and check that the data is present.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code from my own project. In here for your scenario for loaddata can be triggered in the button click. Then it will fetch data and fill the result list. Then in item builder it will display each item one by one. Hope this code will be helpful.

```
 List<Model> resultList ;

  void loaddata() async{
    this.resultList = await getAllResults();
    this.setState(() { });
    print(this.resultList);
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  new Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        resultList != null  ?Expanded(
          child: resultList.length >0? SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.7,
            child: new ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              itemCount: resultList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                  child: GestureDetector(onTap: (){
                  }, child: Text(resultList[index].name)),
                );
              },
            ),
          ): SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.7,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                customTextWidget("No Results."),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ):Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.7,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              CircularProgressIndicator(),
              Text(""),
              customTextWidget("Loading"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and effective way to retrieve data is to use Future Builder. Can be used effectively whenever there is a need to get data from Future Object either HTTP request or Local Database retrival.

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: _query(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.data == null) {
                return Container(
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text("Loading ... "),
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return ListTile(
                        leading: CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                              'https://icons-for-free.com/iconfiles/png/512/badge+business+circle+human+id+male+man+people+person+profile-1320184105268408486.png'),
                        ),
                        title: Text(snapshot.data[index].name),
                        subtitle: Text(snapshot.data[index].email),
                      );
                    });
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

---

```
  Future<List<User>> _query() async {
    final dbHelper = DatabaseHelper.instance;
    final allRows = await dbHelper.queryAllRows();
    print(allRows.length);

    for (int i = 0; i < allRows.length; i++) {
      users.add(User.fromMap(allRows[i])); //Work
      //users[i].toMap();
    }
    print(users[1].name); // Work Fine
    return users;
  }
```